# How do I generate a Dart client library for my Google Cloud Endpoints API using discoveryapis_generator?

Tags: dart, google-cloud-endpoints, google-oauth

I have an endpoints API that I'm accessing with a Dart client library generated with `discoveryapis_generator`. All is well and good except that the generated library doesn't appear to reflect the authentication requirements of my API.

Is it only necessary to somehow create an authenticated `http` object to pass to my application's `BrowserClient()` constructor in the following line?

```dart
my_api = new MyApi(new BrowserClient());
```

Is the recommended method for creating the authenticated `http` object to use the `googleapis_auth` package as described [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis_auth#client-side-web-application)? Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authentication is not part of the API itself. It is actually the http client that will send the proper http header for user authentication. Assuming you use the standard google auth mechanism, you can use the package `https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/googleapis_auth` as you would for a standard Google API (Drive, etc...).

You will have to create a clientId (google console) and use BrowserOAuth2Flow to get an AuthClient (that extends http.client) and from then do `new MyApi(authClient)`

I have a (quite old) project where I override the standard behavior of google auth to allow specifying a userId (never really found the doc on that but it works) during authentication with a simple example that use the PlusApi to get the user name but it could work in a similar way for your own api. Maybe that could help https://github.com/alextekartik/tekartik_googleapis_auth.dart

I think you need at least the `email` scope when calling `createImplicitBrowserFlow`

There are also samples for using google apis that could help: https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis_examples

Comment: Thanks. Following the instructions for creating an authenticated HTTP client for a web app, worked. It was very easy. Looking for the name using the Plus API is interesting. I hadn't thought of that. The email scope is indeed needed: `var scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'];`

Comment: I discovered that successfully authenticating with an email address listed in the IAM console as a project or App Engine admin is insufficient to make the `users.is_current_user_admin()` call in my endpoints service return True. So I wonder what magical OAuth incantation is required for this.

Comment: As a workaround for the above, I maintain a list of administrator email addresses in the service module. Fortunately, the `endpoints.get_current_user()` call succeeds so as to check the returned `user.email()` against this list. I can't think of any real security pitfalls in doing so.